# Show a default hidden <tbody> in table when button clicked

Tags: html, css

I like to create a simple table with has a default hidden tbody, so when i click a button. It will be display in align with my thead.

Here's my html

```
    <div id="show">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alvin</td>
                    <td>Eclair</td>
                    <td>$0.87</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <a href="#show">Show table body</a>
```

And CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #show:target tbody td{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        tbody td{
            display: none;
        }
     </style>
```

Comment: You cant do it with just html or css javascript is must

Comment: sorry im new here, but, i did try to place visibility: hidden to my tbody td but the problem, it takes spaces

Comment: see `visibility:hidden` by default leave space but hide the element and `display :none` completely hides the element but you need to write some script for showing the element on `<a>` click. see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do it with little jquery

```
$('#show').on('click', function(){
  $('tbody td').css('display','table-cell');
});
```

Comment: It did get rid of the spaces when i put display:block, but when i click on it, it will get a space but still nothing to show, i input your little jquery with it